# Building FormData object from form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, multipartform-data

My FormData object will not get data from my pages form element. The appended data goes through and is displayed when I do a `var_dump($_POST)` in the PHP file, however the form data is not there. Without the append, it is just an empty array.

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $("form").on("submit", function() {
        var formData = new FormData($("#form")[0]);
        formData.append("Hello world", "This is a test");
        $.ajax({
            url: "sub/addCrane.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            $("#form").append(data);
        });
    });
});
```

HTML form:

```
<form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#">

    <p class="inline">Crane Model: </p><input type="text" id="model"><br />
    <p class="inline">Crane Brand: </p><input type="text" id="brand"><br />
    <p class="inline">Crane type (ie. Crawler, Tower, Mobile): </p><input type="text" id="type"><br />
    <p class="inline">Image of crane: </p><input type="file" id="image">
    <input type="submit" id="submit">

</form>
```

Comment: Check your response `console.log(data)' in `done()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're using `id` instead of `name` in your input tags, which doesn't let JQuery play nice with them, and so it ignores them. Also, it's not common practice, and PHP doesn't really like it either :)

Cheers!

Comment: Will this send the file also?

Comment: And sorry for the silly question, self teaching JQuery meant I missed a lot, but if my form is now `<form name='myForm'>` do I just call it in JQuery with `$('myForm')`?

Comment: Ah, sorry, let me clarify. You need to use 'name' in the input tags, though using a name for the form is also beneficial. To answer that question, though, yes, that's the selector you'd use

Comment: Thank you so much! First question on stackoverflow and it went so well!

Comment: Come back more often, we're mostly really nice :D

Answer (score 0):

Try next:

```
$("#form").submit(function () {

var formData = new FormData();
jQuery.each($('#image')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    formData.append('file-'+i, file);
});

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'sub/addCrane.php',
            data: formData,
            success: function (answer) {
                console.log(answer);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: formData is not defined in the example?